# Uniting two statements in SQL (using JOIN or more efficient way)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join, subtraction

I made two statements -  SUM of revenue and expenses in different tables using group by id (each id has more than one revenue and expenses records):

```
select id_person, SUM (revenue_d) as sum_revenue from sales group by id_person;

select id_person, SUM (expenses_d) as sum_expenses from expenses group by id_person;
```

Now I need to subtract expenses.sum_expenses from sales.sum_revenue.

What is a more efficient way to do so?

Using JOINs? Something like that:

```
SELECT id_person, (sales.sum_revenue - expenses.sum_expenses) as balance FROM sales LEFT OUTER JOIN expenses ON sales.id_person = expenses.id_person;
```

**But how to write all three statements in one?**

```
SELECT id_person, (sales.sum_revenue - expenses.sum_expenses) as balance 
FROM (select id_person, SUM (revenue_d) as sum_revenue from sales group by id_person)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select id_person, SUM (expenses_d) as sum_expenses from expenses group by id_person) 
ON sales.id_person = expenses.id_person;`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for subqueries.

Assuming the sales has at least as many person_ids as expenses

You can do

```
SELECT 
    s.id_person,
    SUM (s.revenue_d) - SUM (COALESCE(e.expenses_d,0))   AS balance
FROM
    sales s
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    expenses e ON s.id_person = e.id_person
GROUP BY s.id_person;
```

Comment: No need to do LEFT JOIN, the result will be the same with an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @jarlh as we don't know the tables, the LEFT JOIN is appropriate or even a FULL OUTER JOIN, if mysql would finally support it, that os why i added the sentence about the number

Comment: Yes, you are correct - and a FULL OUTER JOIN would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

First `UNION ALL`, then `GROUP BY`:

```
select id_person, sum(revenue_d) as sum_revenue, sum(expenses_d) as sum_expenses 
from
(
    select id_person, revenue_d, null as expenses_d from sales
    union all
    select id_person, null, expenses_d from expenses
) dt
group by id_person;
```

Or, if you also have a persons table:

```
select p.id_person, sum(s.revenue_d) as sum_revenue, sum(e.expenses_d) as sum_expenses 
from persons p
left join sales s on p.id_person = s.id_person
left join expenses e on p.id_person = e.id_person
group by p.id_person
```